# Failure to install software from Software Center

Tags: 10.10, software-center, kubuntu

I have recently installed Ubuntu version 10.10 but I cannot install any software from the Software Center.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Any error messages? You tagged this as "kubuntu-desktop", did you mean "Kubuntu 10.10" instead of "Ubuntu 10.10"?

Comment: also how did you install the software center in kubuntu?

Comment: Can you post your sources.list? See [How do I find all of my software sources?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26047/6969) for a how-to.

Comment: Are you connected to the internet?

Answer (score 2):

Do a few things.

1. make sure you've got an active internet connection.
2. Make sure your internet is plugged in or connected to your system.
3. in terminal, run `sudo apt-get update`.
4. Tell us if that worked, otherwise tell us the error from the output.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo apt-get update` in terminal to update your package list