# How do I find all of my software sources?

Tags: apt, software-sources, repository

Broken software dependencies are often caused by incompatible third party repositories.

I am asked to provide a list of software sources (also known as software repositories). How can I quickly get a list of software sources?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Software repositories as used for `apt-get` are set in `/etc/apt/sources.list`.

`apt-add-repository` adds additional repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. Note that the extension is `.list` too. To find all occurences of these `*.list` files, run the next command [in a terminal window](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal):

```
find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \;
```

It will provide all useful information regarding software repositories used by `apt`. If this list is very long, and a file is preffered, use the next command to create a file in the current directory, named `repositories.txt`:

```
find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \; > repositories.txt
```

To post this list on Askubuntu, go to http://paste.ubuntu.com/ and paste the list in the big text field. Submit the form by pressing "Paste!" and copy the URL from the location bar (which should look like "http://paste.ubuntu.com/566454/"). Finally, paste this URL in your question.

Comment: As a refinement of that find command, you can use this answer : http://askubuntu.com/questions/28644/how-can-i-backup-my-ppas/28655#28655

Answer (score 1):

If you want a GUI, it’s any of these:

- Update Manager → Settings,
- Software Centre → Software Sources,
- Synaptic Package Manager → Repositories.