# How can I be sure that the updated packages are not compromised?

Tags: updates, security

When trying to install `tmux` I get an error that `Untrusted packages could compromise your system's security`, similar to the situation in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/28195/untrusted-packages-could-compromise-your-systems-security-appears-while-tryin). I ran `aptitude update` and the package installed without issue, but I am concerned that the update may have been compromised. My concern in enhanced as I see that the update was done without SSL (http address):

```
 - neptune():~$ sudo aptitude update
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates InRelease
Ign http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports InRelease
Get: 1 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release.gpg [933 B]
Get: 2 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release.gpg [933 B]
Get: 3 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-backports Release.gpg [933 B]
Hit http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal Release
Get: 4 http://il.archive.ubuntu.com quantal-updates Release [49.6 kB]
Ign http://security.ubuntu.com quantal-security InRelease
Ign http://archive.canonical.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://extras.ubuntu.com quantal InRelease
Ign http://dl.google.com stable InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable InRelease
Ign http://ppa.launchpad.net quantal InRelease
```

**EDIT:** I have now been made aware that the [targeted attacking of Israeli websites](http://blogs.jpost.com/content/hackers-will-target-israel-again-april-7) on April 7 has already begun. Therefore, there is increased suspicion of a compromised server. I could find more information about the attack if necessary, though I don't see much mention of it in widespread English-language news websites.

**Clarification:** I'm asking how to ensure that *what I've already downloaded and installed* is not compromised. I am not asking how Canonical ensures the security of repos.

Comment: Have you considered tunnelling out over TOR? It might be a slow update but it'd be secure.

Comment: @Gregology Tunnelling won't make the package itself more secure if it was compromised, and is being pulled from the same server. One would need to use an actual different server that has not been compromised, and has the properly signed packages.

Comment: Hi @dobey, I disagree. Tunnelling over TOR will make a man in the middle attack very unlikely and if the actual server has been compromised then packages could be falsely signed anyway. I would suggest using another server though. What are you thoughts @dobey?

Comment: @Gregology You're assuming it's a MitM attack. And I think this question is a duplicate. I'd suggest using a different mirror of course. :)

Comment: Thanks, all. Had I been concerned _before_ downloading, then this would be a dup (i.e., how do I know that the repo is safe). However, I'm now asking how to ensure that _what I've already downloaded and installed_ is not compromised.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot tell you how you do it for **all** packages, but here is a possible procedure for single packages.

**Warning**: The site I suggest to use does (strangely) not support **https** yet - so you cannot be certain that you are really talking to the correct site, which makes the check much less useful than expected - as Eliah Kagan pointed out in a comment.

1. visit [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com)
2. select your distro
3. select "all packages" (down at the bottom)
4. look into `/var/cache/apt/archives` and choose suspicious packages (for instance those with a recent date)
5. run a `sha256sum` against that package
6. choose that package on the website, you get 
   [image]
7. click on  the link beneath **Architecture**
   [image]
8. compare the result from step 5 with the published value.

Comment: Interestingly, the site does not show a result when I search for `tmux_1.6-2_amd64` or `tmux_1.6-2_amd64.deb`, but google takes me to the right page.

Comment: Manually checking the hashes of your packages like this won't make you any more secure--they are already checked automatically by APT for any package automatically downloaded. And http://packages.ubuntu.com is not SSL-secured; if you don't trust the hashes that are *GPG-signed*, why trust hashes obtained naively from an HTTP site??

Comment: @EliahKagan the question was about the warning "Untrusted packages could compromise..."

Comment: @guntbert But this is still an insecure way to verify a package's integrity or authenticity. I've removed my comment on the question (I'm no longer so sure this is a duplicate). But this answer still has the severe shortcoming that it uses an untrusted channel to obtain the sha256 hash. Furthermore, by presenting your method as "the procedure," you're strongly suggesting that this is widely considered a secure method. Under some circumstances this *may* be better than nothing, but isn't there another way to check them? Launchpad? (Which is HTTPS-secured, and is where the packages *originate*.)

Comment: @guntbert Thanks. Since there don't seem to be hashes listed on Launchpad, to really be sure (without using APT's built-in system that automatically retrieves the hashes, checks that they are properly GPG-signed, then checks .deb packages against the hashes), it would be necessary to [download the package from Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-firefox-extension) and compare. Really, I think the best option is to use APT to fix the "untrusted packages" problem and verify the packages. Once the proper keys are imported, reinstalling them should achieve this.

Comment: @EliahKagan but that would be a new answer, I guess - feel free :-))

Comment: @guntbert Hopefully someone who knows how to perform that full procedure will post such an answer. :) Or maybe I'll eventually get around to figuring it out.

Answer (score 2):

### Don't worry.

As Eliah explained in [his comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/278198/how-can-i-be-sure-that-the-updated-packages-are-not-compromised/279360#comment349459_278311), APT is secured using GnuPG. The public keys for the archives of Ubuntu are installed on your system and you should check those. After every download the file will be checked for integrity by the GPG/PGP signature and thus you can be sure nobody has tampered with. In case that fails, you'll see the exact warning you got in the first place.

A more thorough explanation, how to find and validate keys is described here: [Ubuntu Community wiki: SecureApt](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SecureApt)

Using SSL won't make it more secure. The only thing you'll be hiding for all peers in between you and the archive server is *what* you're transferring/downloading and it won't protect anything more in respect to *integrity*.