# How to repair apt-get command?

Tags: apt, dpkg

When I try to install new package with `apt-get install`, it doesn't work. `apt-get update` doesn't work too.

Do you know how to reinstall it to work again?

Output from **sudo dpkg --configure -a** :

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tvbrowser:
 tvbrowser depends on sun-java6-jre | sun-java5-jre; however:
  Package sun-java6-jre is not installed.
  Package sun-java5-jre is not installed.
dpkg: error processing tvbrowser (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tvbrowser
```

Output from **sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre**

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package sun-java6-jre is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package sun-java6-jre has no installation candidate
```

[This pastebin](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/590890/) has the output of `find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \; > repositories.txt` .

Comment: Provide more information please, like error messages. Please run `LC_ALL=C sudo apt-get install [package-name]` (replace `[package-name]` with the package you're trying to install) and report the error messages.

Comment: I wrote error message to the robin0800 answer. LC_ALL=C is some command?

Comment: @xralf Please add the details to your question, not someone's answer. Adding `LC_ALL=C` before a program sets the environment variable `LC_ALL` to `C`. This makes a command using the English language (assuming you're not using an English system).

Comment: OK, error message is similar as in my answer.

Comment: @xralf: The package `sun-java6-jre` package can be found in the partner repository. Can you post your [repository sources](http://askubuntu.com/q/26047/6969)?

Comment: Could you please learn me how to solve it? How to find out that it's in the partner repository, in which repository it is and what to edit and why this caused this strange problem?

Comment: @xralf: Can you post your repository sources (described in my last comment)? `tvbrowser` is not part of the Ubuntu repository by default.

Comment: So, how did you find out that it is not part? And why this caused that error? There should happen some error in the apt-get application.
Where can I post the output of "cat /etc/apt/sources.list"? It's quite a long file.

Comment: @xralf you can put it on pastebin.ubuntu.com

Comment: @xralf see [How do I find all of my software sources?](http://askubuntu.com/q/26047/6969). Using just `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` is not enough, you might have added some addition stuff in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`

Comment: [This](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/590890/) is the output of "find /etc/apt/ -name '*.list' -ls -exec cat {} \; > repositories.txt"

Comment: @xralf Can you add this information to your original question? Comments get buried, it's best to put as much information in your question by editing it, thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What I am noticing from your output of the error is this:

`dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of tvbrowser:`

Try:

```
 sudo apt-get -f install
```

This should satisfy dependencies not met when you installed a .deb file in Ubuntu. It may end up asking you if it is ok to download those dependencies.

Hope this helps, if it helps.

Answer (score 12):

The standard way to repair the `dpkg` database is to use this command:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

Answer (score 1):

The error you are getting explains what packages are missing.

Do the following in terminal, and it will fix the dependency issue:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre
```

That should immediately fix any issues you are having.

Comment: Note this does not work in Oneiric or later.