# GIMP installation error

Tags: software-installation

[image]

I am trying to install GIMP through the terminal.. But The following error is showing..

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running Ubuntu 16.10?

Comment: You can also use `aptitude`, it's smarter than `apt-get` and will help with dependencies.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244851/ubuntu-20-04-error-on-install-gimp-depends-libgimp2-0-2-10-18-but-it-is/1244864#1244864

Answer (score 3):

Run the following commands to clear out the package cache, resolve dependencies, and (hopefully) fix install issues:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install gimp
```

Breaking this down a bit more:

- **`sudo apt update`**
  This command will download new package caches and package data from the Ubuntu servers.
- **`sudo apt -f install`**
  This command, known as "fix all the problems" will attempt to smartly resolve any dependency issues, and re-install any broken packages. In your case, it will likely re-install the missing GEGL library.
- **`sudo apt full-upgrade`**
  This command runs a full upgrade of all of your software to bring you up to the latest version. Note that it does not change your OS version, so it won't upgrade 14.04 to 16.04.
- **`sudo apt install gimp`**
  This command installs `gimp`, as one can guess.

Comment: Sorry dear.. its not working for me..

Comment: @VishuuTiwari What error message (if any different) is being thrown?

Comment: Here is tha following full error message:

Comment: Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgegl-0.3-0 (>= 0.3.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Comment: @VishuuTiwari What happens if you run `sudo apt install libgegl-0.3-0`?

Comment: The same error is popping out

Comment: I have added the image link in the question.. please reffer to it

Comment: @VishuuTiwari Do you have any third-party PPAs installed?

Comment: I dont know.. actually  i am new to ubuntu. Can u tell me how to know if there is any 3rd party PPa installed or not..

Comment: @VishuuTiwari [See here](http://askubuntu.com/a/26048/208574).

Comment: I am not getting it.

Answer (score 0):

For me the above answer didn't fix the problem. Apparently due to a dependency error with libgegl-0.4-0 gimp can't be installed.

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

This line fixes this problem.
Found here:
[Upgrade libgegl-0.4-0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1244868/libgegl-0-4-0-package-upgrade-problem)