# Ubuntu 20.04 error on install gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.10.18) but it is not going to be installed

Tags: apt, 20.04, gimp

I have this issue when I search to install Gimp:

```
$ sudo apt-get install gimp 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gimp : Depends: libgimp2.0 (>= 2.10.18) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgimp2.0 (<= 2.10.18-z) but it is not going to be installed
        Depends: libgegl-0.4-0 (>= 0.4.22) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Nothing change after apt update & upgrade.
Do you have a solution for me? Thanks to

Best,

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy gimp` to the question.

Comment: Same issue. I ended up installing with snap on Ubuntu 20.04. 

`snap install gimp`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One solution is to use `aptitude`. It is generally smarter than `apt-get` at resolving dependencies.

First, install `aptitude`:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then install Gimp using `aptitude`:

```
sudo aptitude install gimp
```

And then after running that, Gimp should be installed.

Comment: Isn't aptitude already installed just `apt`?

Comment: @larkey no, they're different things.

Comment: Hm, can't remember where I picked that up.

Comment: Quoted from the Debian wiki. Aptitude has a "_score-based dependency resolver which is more suitable for interactive dependency resolution with additional hints from the user like "I don't want that part of the solution but keep that other part of the solution for your next try". Apt's dependency resolver on the other hand is optimized for good "one shot" solutions._"

Comment: Using aptitude I get: "The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libopenexr23 which is a virtual package and is not provided by any available package

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     gimp [Not Installed]                               
2)     libgegl-0.4-0 [Not Installed]                      
3)     libgimp2.0 [Not Installed]                         
Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] " So it seems there is no solution with aptitude either.

Comment: Ok, nevermind you have to say "n" and it proposes another "solution" this time a real one since it installs the missing dependency.

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.:)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend installing Gimp as a flatpak, as the flatpak is maintained by the gimp developers.

```
sudo apt install flatpak

flatpak install flathub org.gimp.GIMP
```

and to run

```
flatpak run org.gimp.GIMP
```

Comment: Does not work on Linux Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Comment: @vitaliis what does not work for you on ubuntu 20.04? it works for me on 20.04 and on 21.04.

Comment: Maybe it's just my configaration: `Note that the directories 

'/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share'
'/home/user/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share'

are not in the search path set by the XDG_DATA_DIRS environment variable, so
applications installed by Flatpak may not appear on your desktop until the
session is restarted.
error: app/org.gimp.GIMP/x86_64/master not installed`

Comment: @vitaliis this seems to be referenced in these bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/debian/+source/lxde-common/+bug/1905289 and upstream here: https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=906288 . Though, you should be able to run the packages nonetheless, even on gnome. I am on Kubuntu at the moment on all my systems, so can not verify if it would work on gnome.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, update and upgrade so everything is fresh:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

Then, try these two commands:

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

They will usually fix broken or unmet dependencies.

You can also look for JUST files related with your package and purge them, then reinstall them:

```
sudo dpkg --list
sudo apt-get purge <file-name>
```

Or you can use `aptitude` in place of `apt` or `apt-get`, `aptitude` is smarter than `apt-get` and will help deal with dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude install gimp
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I would reorder the commands. As very first to a `apt-get update` (or `apt` or `aptitude` this does not matter here). This will make sure that the package list is recent and consistent and any problems that may have been resolved in the meantime are gone. There is a certain chance that this was a bug in the packaging and usually such bugs are detected and fixed quickly.