# libgegl-0.4-0 package upgrade problem

Tags: apt, upgrade

```
sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease   
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease    
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/otto-kesselgulasch/gimp/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://pl.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
1 package can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see it.

apt list --upgradable
Listing... Done
libgegl-0.4-0/focal 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.22-3]
N: There is 1 additional version. Please use the '-a' switch to see it

apt list --upgradable -a
Listing... Done
libgegl-0.4-0/focal 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa amd64 [upgradable from: 0.4.22-3]
libgegl-0.4-0/focal,now 0.4.22-3 amd64 [installed,upgradable to: 1:0.4.18+om-0ubu20.04.18~ppa]

sudo apt install libgegl-0.4-0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libgegl-0.4-0 : Depends: libopenexr23 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

sudo apt install libopenexr23
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libopenexr23 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libopenexr24:i386 libopenexr24

E: Package 'libopenexr23' has no installation candidate
```

libgegl-0.4-0 can be upgraded but cant ?
I am on Kubuntu 20.04

Comment: `sudo apt full-upgrade`  `apt list --upgradable` shows only which packages could be upgradet. It does nothing more.

Comment: sudo apt full-upgrade says 0 were upgraded, 0 uninstalled, 0 newly installed and 0 not upgraded

Comment: `sudo apt install libopenexr24` and `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d` please.

Comment: libopenexr24 is already installed and newest version

https://pastebin.com/YV1Y4kEC

Comment: Also can i safely remove the libopenexr23 ?

Comment: any chance you has https://launchpad.net/~otto-kesselgulasch/+archive/ubuntu/gimp  ppa bound in and removed it?

Answer (score 15):

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge && sudo ppa-purge ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
```

This seems to fix it

Comment: This one solved it after trying many other solutions.

Comment: Could you explain more what this does? How did you known gimp was responsible? I don't find this precise ppa when running `grep -r --include '*.list' '^deb ' /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` (https://askubuntu.com/a/741948/800252) but I do see another gimp related ppa `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/otto-kesselgulasch-ubuntu-gimp-focal.list` would it be causing my problems as well. Should I run the same command? How would I know?

Answer (score 0):

The following command will work: `sudo apt install libopenexr-dev`